# C# Why does Decimal math return zero?

Tags: c#

I have a method in an ASP.net MVC project that is supposed to pull the sum of some values from some lists, add them together and then multiply them by a value. The lists are pulled from a SQL table, stored as decimal values, and when I retrieve the Sum of the values using Linq, they are decimal values. But when I try to multiply, or add, the values by each other the result is always zero.

```
private Decimal LLR = 0.00284M;
private Decimal GetStandardReserveForLoan(List<Loan> loans, List<LineOfCredit> locs)    
{
    decimal l = locs.Sum(x => x.MaxCredit ?? 0M);
    decimal loan = loans.Sum(x => x.LoanAmount ?? 0M);
    decimal subtotal = loan + l;
    decimal total = subtotal * LLR;
    return total;
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the `decimal total =` line and look at the locals, `subtotal = 0` and `total = 0`. I can even go into the immediate window and add `loan + l` together and `17500.00`, and multiply `(loan + l) * LLR` and get `49.7`.

Why is it that I can get the correct values in the immediate window, but the method will not return the correct value?

Comment: make sure `loans` and `locs` list are not empty and those values are not null.  see what number this code returns `locs.Where(x=>x.MaxCredit!=null).Count()`. if it returns zero then it means MaxCredit numbers are all null. do the same for loans.

Comment: you need to provide more info here. How were you calling it and you got 0. during debug you were seeing the right value, what if you step all the way to return and see what the return value is?

Comment: if you think weird things are happening go to project properties and disable `Optimize code` for debug mode.

Comment: @steve I am calling the method in my Controller, to display the value on a page. It displays a 0. I have confirmed that the value for l = 17500 and loan = 0. The loans list is empty right now.

Comment: Yeah something is definitely up with your configuration. I mocked some data and your code works as is: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5hZIs

Comment: maybe data binding doesn't work if you are working with UI

Comment: @dropped_pocket what about that return value? Have you step thru your code and see what the return value is? The UI display should be ignored for now

Comment: @steve The actual value the controller pulls in is 0.00000

Comment: just to make sure. when you have the debugger attached, you are seeing l is 17500 and 0 for return value? do one step at a time, don't just skip the steps and go straight to result

Comment: Yes, I put a break point on each line in the method starting with subtotal = and going through to the end, then inside the controller method where I call the method to display on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The input values you are passing to `Sum()` are probably empty. From the `Sum()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298138(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Sum(IEnumerable) method returns zero if source contains no elements.

Comment: @Steve I think he's mistaken. When you run his code with the data mocked, it works just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5hZIs

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the calculation by adding an explicit decimal point to the nullable return value of `loan`, by changing the line like so:

```
decimal loan = loans.Sum(x => x.LoanAmount ?? 0.00M);
```

The method now correctly return 49.700000 for me.

Comment: **That would not fix the problem that was stated**. Therefore there was some other problem that you fixed at the same time, probably whatever problem it was that you accidentally caused in the first place. You were looking at the wrong value in the debugger, or you had optimizations turned on and the debugger was showing an outdated value, or whatever.  Changing 0M to 0.00M would have no effect on whatever was causing the original issue.

Comment: Regardless though, if the problem is no longer reproducible then please close or delete the question so that you stop wasting the time of people trying to help you.